# Implementing component require property in Angular 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, components, angular-directive

I am having no joy with implementing `require: {}` property as part of an angular component. Allow me to demonstrate with an example I have.

This is the component/directive that supposed to fetch a list of judgements. Nothing very fancy, just a simple factory call.

```
// judgements.component.js
function JudgementsController(GetJudgements) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.Get = function () {
        GetJudgements.get().$promise.then(
            function (data) {
                ctrl.Judgements = data.judgements;
            }, function (error) {
                // show error message
            });
    }

    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        ctrl.Get();
    };
}

angular
    .module('App')
    //.component('cJudgements', {
    //    controller: JudgementsController,
    //});
    .directive('cJudgements', function () {
        return {
            scope: true,
            controller: 'JudgementsController',
            //bindToController: true,
        };
    });
```

I am trying to implement component require property to give me access to `ctrl.Judgements` from the above component/directive as follows:

```
// list.component.js
function ListController(GetList, GetJudgements) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.list = [];

    ctrl.Get = function () {
        GetList.get().$promise.then(
            function (data) {
                ctrl.list = data.list;
            }, function (error) {
                // show error message
            });
    };

    //ctrl.GetJudgements = function () {
    //    GetJudgements.get().$promise.then(
    //        function (data) {
    //            ctrl.Judgements = data.judgements;
    //        }, function (error) {
    //            // show error message
    //        });
    //}

    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        ctrl.Get();
        //ctrl.GetJudgements();
    };
}

angular
    .module('App')
    .component('cTheList', {
        bindings: {
            listid: '<',
        },
        controller: ListController,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        require: {
            jCtrl: 'cJudgements',
        },
        template: `
            <c-list-item ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list"
                         item="item"
                         judgements="ctrl.Judgements"></c-list-item>
           <!--
           obviously the reference to judgements here needs to change
           or even better to be moved into require of cListItem component
           -->
        `,
    });
```

Nice and simple no magic involved. A keen reader probably noticed `GetJudgement` service call in the `ListController`. This is what I am trying to remove from `TheList` component using require property.

The reason? Is actually simple. I want to stop database being hammered by Judgement requests as much as possible. It's a static list and there is really no need to request it more than once per instance of the app.

So far I have only been successful with receiving the following error message:

```
Error: $compile:ctreq
Missing Required Controller
Controller 'cJudgements', required by directive 'cTheList', can't be found!
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am using angular 1.5
PSS: I do not mind which way cJudgement is implemented (directive or component).
PSSS: If someone wonders I have tried using `jCtrl: '^cJudgements'`.
PSSSS: And multiple `^`s for that matter just in case.

#### Edit

@Kindzoku posted a link to [the article](https://toddmotto.com/on-init-require-object-syntax-angular-component/) that I have read before posting the question. I hope this also helps someone in understanding `$onInit` and `require` in Angular 1.5+.

#### Plunker

Due to popular demand I made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8yL3WnZjRaqlanvsQXPn?p=preview) example.

Comment: what above error means is, there is no parent html element defined with controller `cJudgements`, btw you will have to inject the service and not require it

Comment: I don't understand your $onInit implementation. It should be like this: this.$onInit = function() { this.method = this.requiredName.requiredMethod() }

Comment: @entre The error simply means that ``cJudgements`` cannot be found. There is no parent html defined with ``cJudgements``. As you can see it is just a wrapper for a service call.

Comment: I guess it's time for heavy artillery. Prepare the Plunker :D

Comment: @Kindzoku Haha, by the time I do that I'll probably find a fix :p I'll try to put one together in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

You should use required components in `this.$onInit = function(){}`

Here is a good article https://toddmotto.com/on-init-require-object-syntax-angular-component/

The $onInit in your case should be written like this:

```
ctrl.$onInit = function () {
    ctrl.jCtrl.Get();
};
```

Comment: I really dont see how does it help the OP?

Comment: Heh, I actually read that article before making my post. Sorry the example I posted doesn't use $onInit but my real code does. I updated the example.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. That's not where the problem is. The problem is in the ``require: { jCtrl: 'cJudgements', }`` Anyways, I'll put a plunker tomorrow morning for everyone to play with.

Answer (score 0):

@iiminov has the right answer. No parent HTML `c-judgements` was defined.

[Working plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/UM7gFTkwxy8LsRy6yEK5?p=preview)